# Which permutations of $\mathbb{C}$ commute with the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I'm trying to figure out whether the permutations of $\mathbb{C}$ which commute with the Riemann $\zeta$ function are necessarily continuous or not. Obviously both the identity and the complex conjugation do the job, but is there another example?
Thanks in advance.